# Search for string and read the next line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, debian, shell

I need to write a *shell* program that installs some packages. The program will run on Linux (obviously some commands will not work, for example, on Arch-based distros).

So, I've got this file called **config.conf** with the following structure:

```
#EMAIL
email address here
#TWITTER
twitter account
#FORUM
a bunch of 'http://foru.ms'
#FACEBOOK

#REDDIT
reddit username
```

The program initial_install.sh should search for the lines that starts with an hash and, if the subsequent line is not empty, install the package needed for that category.
For example, it searches for #TWITTER and, *only* if a twitter account is written just below that line, it installs the *rainbowstream* twitter client with `sudo apt-get install rainbowstream`.

Can you help me? I have no ideas, i'm not really a 'shell expert'..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with *grep*

```
  cat filename | grep -A1 TWITTER | grep -v TWITTER
```

or, perhaps better, you can do it with *awk*

```
  awk '/TWITTER/{getline; print}' filename
```

Comment: uhm, understood what 'cat' will do: it seems it prints the line next to the one with the given word. But 1) i don't want to show THAT output (maybe --silent can solve it?) and i need something like 'if the line printed is not empty, do $this'...ideas?